# How to make a property or whatever to hold specific data .net

Tags: c#, .net, collections, properties

I have a class that hold some properties I need one of those properties to hold only some values

mean when I need to set a value I need to accept only value from an already defined enum

so when I use the class and on this property I could only use a value from enum

I just need to make sure that this property doesn't hold other values that I don't know in my enum

If there any solution other than using property it's ok :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Iam not sure if I understood you right, but don't you simply want this:

```
enum MyEnum 
{
  MyValue1,
  MyValue2
}    

class Test
{
  public MyEnum MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

Another way would be to define the property as `string` or `int` (or whatever type your enum is based on) and check if the value is valid according to the enum:

```
string _value;

public string MyProperty 
{
  get{return _value;}
  set {
   if (Enum.GetName(typeof(MyEnum), _value)==null) 
      throw new ArgumentException("Unknown Value")
   _value=value;
   }
}
```

If you make your property integer based, you can use `Enum.IsDefined()` to check if the integer value is valid for that enum.

You may also want to consider usage of ***C#4.0 Code Contracts***.

Answer (score 2):

```
private int _field
public int Property
{
    get{ return _field;}
    set{
        if (Enum.GetValues(typeof(SomeEnum))).Contains(value))
            _field = value;
        else 
            _field = 0;
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean this:

```
public enum SomeEnum { item1, item2, item3 };
public class Myclass
{
    private SomeEnum enumItem;
    public SomeEnum EnumItem
    {
        get { return enumItem; }
        set { enumItem = value; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There're some object validation libraries. I'd like to suggest you NHibernate Validator.

It could sound like it has a dependency with NHibernate, but it can be used standalone.

NH Validator and others are attribute-oriented, so you can place an attribute for your properties and then, by calling a validation engine, you'll be able to ensure some object property would hold some expected value or any other validation rule.

Learn more here:

- http://nhforge.org/wikis/validator/nhibernate-validator-1-0-0-documentation.aspx

EDIT: I forgot to mention NH Validator has an extensibility API so you can implement your own validation rules, fact that should make sense for you!